# Unable to install SQL server 2019 Express Edition (setup.exe)

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me on this one.
I an trying to install SQL Server 2019 express version on my windows 10 laptop for the first time. But I get an error:

> Exit code (decimal): -2068052293Error description: There is problem with this windows installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

**Here is the image showing error:**
[Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKLgW.png)

Can anyone help me how to solve the problem?

Comment: I hope you have read the system requirements for SQL Server 2019 (especially Windows 10 TH1 1507 or greater)

Comment: Yeah, i have windows 10 pro version  21H2.
i think it satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the latest [Latest cumulative update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)